# Laravel Expected response code 250 but got code "530" al restablacer contraseña

Tags: laravel

estoy teniendo este error: `Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required "`

Aparece cuando trato de restablecer una contraseña (Ingreso a la pagina de recover, pongo el correo y hago clic en enviar)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

fui a el archivo env y coloque esto:

````
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com    
MAIL_PORT=465    
MAIL_USERNAME=ivanedu947@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl```

y en mail.php
````

````
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),


'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),


'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'ivanedu947@gmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Prueba'),
],

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

'username' => env('ivanedu947@gmail.com'),

'password' => env('password'),

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs'```
````

Pero aun luego de haber configurado todo eso, me sigue dando el error: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required ", espero puedan ayudarme y agradezco de antemano.

Comment: ¿Ya configuraste el servidor SMTP para enviar los mensajes? En tu .env hay algunos datos que debes llenar.

Comment: Otra cosa, En gmail debes desactivar la seguridad de dos pasos para que puedas enviar los mensajes y no los tomen como spam. Te dejo el link de un tuto que segui hace tiempo para que puedas usar gmail [tuto gmail laravel](https://programacionymas.com/blog/como-enviar-mails-correos-desde-laravel). O puedes usar mailtrap para trabajar con tu aplicacion. Si deseas esta segunda, dime y voy redactando la respuesta

Comment: Por cierto el puerto es el 587 y tu en tu archivo `.env` le dices que esta en el puerto 465

Comment: Asumiré que ese email es falso, de otro modo que riesgo de seguridad

Answer (score 1):

tienes mal estas dos lineas

```
'username' => env('ivanedu947@gmail.com'),

'password' => env('password'),
```

deben ir asi

```
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','ivanedu947@gmail.com'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','password'),
```

El primer parametro es la llave del archivo .env y el segundo es el valor por defecto

Answer (score 0):

En realidad lo que pasa es que cada vez que editas el archivo .env debes reiniciar el servidor. Para hacer esto presiona Ctrl + C en la terminal y vuelve a ejecutar `php artisan serve`.

Al menos asi es en local.